There is different in user control Size between design Mode and runtime Mode

I use Visualbasic.net 2012.
I changed user control form Auto scale mode = Inherit
and normal form  Auto scale mode = Font because it is the default value in Windows Form.
i have this result.
I design the same control in pc with processor 32bit Windows7 and i haven't this problem, but with processor 64bit Windows11 i have the problem.
I change Auto scale mode for windows form to all option (dpi, non, font, inherit)
I changed user control form Auto scale mode to Inherit
and Windows form to (dpi, Font, Non, Inherit)

why do you use Vs 2012, maybe you should thik about installing VS 2022 and try your programs there with modern net 7 or 8

Your application is not DPI Aware. Follow the guidelines here: How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting (e.g. 150%)? to change that. As mentioned, if possible, move to VS 2022 and use a recent .NET version, better if it's .NET 8 -- A Form is not a UserControl
